# How to use Curl to make a POST request with Dropwizard

Tags: rest, curl, dropwizard

I have  Dropwizard backend end and like to use curl to make a POST request with a Json body

I used Postman with the settings on the body tab `raw` radio button selected and on the drop down menu `JSON(applicattion/json)`.I  entered the body and was able to successfully create a POST request. 
However when I used curl I get an error. I used

```
curl -v  -X POST "localhost:8080/resource" 
-H "Content-Type: application/json" 
-d '{label1: "words1", label2: "words2"}'
```

I get the error message

```
 {"code":400,"message":"Unable to process JSON"}
```

From my understanding it is curl that has an issue since Postman was able to create the POST request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
{label1: "words1", label2: "words2"}
```

is not JSON. Use

```
{"label1": "words1", "label2": "words2"}
```

Comment: Danke, Lutz. it was a typo on my part